# Saving multiple files while taking screenshots

Tags: powershell, screenshot

```
$n = 0
timeout 5
while ($n -le 10) {
   [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

   function screenshot([Drawing.Rectangle]$bounds, $path) {
     $bmp = New-Object Drawing.Bitmap $bounds.width, $bounds.height
     $graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

     $graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

     $bmp.Save($path)

     $graphics.Dispose()
     $bmp.Dispose()
  }

  $bounds = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB(0, 0, 3840, 2160)
  screenshot $bounds "C:\screenshot.png"

  [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{right}") 

  $n = $n + 1
}
```

So I'm trying to take a screenshot, move right and then take another screenshot 9 times. However, all screenshots get saved to one single file "screenshot.png". How do I fix this and save into multiple files?

Comment: Put `$n` in the filename;  `"c:\screenshot.$n.png"`